# Flex get iframe text value

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, apache-flex, iframe

I am using an iframe layered over my flex application. In my iframe i have a text input with the id of 'days' which is read only.

How can i read the value of days in my flex app?

I thought i may need to do something like this?

```
var d = ExternalInterface.call("top.frames[0].document.getElementById('days').value");
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work?  Did you get an error?  Or some other unexpected results?  How are you displaying the iFrame?  Are you using one of the libraries to make that work?  Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work, because `top.frames[0].document.getElementById('days').value` is not a function, it's a property. You need to pass function to `ExternalInterface.call` (more precisely the name of a function). For example, you can define in JavaScript (main window)

```
top.GetValue = function(id) {
    return frames[0].document.getElementById(id).value;
}
```

and then use

```
var d = ExternalInterface.call('top.GetValue', 'days');
```

in ActionScript.